# jQuery UI Sortable Triggered when an Items are re-arranged or moved in between lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need a jQuery UI Sortable event that fires ONLY when the item is dragged from one list to another, or ordered within the same list it is actually placed.

I also need to know from which list it came.

I have tried the event called `stop`, but it seems like this never sends the Sender event.

What can I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you are looking for is

### [Update](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)

> This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM
>   position has changed.

Whether you re-order the same list or drag items between different lists, the `update` event will be triggered on respective sortable and the `ui` will contain `sender` as well.

Answer (score -1):

As I found out, moments after posting this question, it can be solved using the event called "receive".

Comment: This answer might have solved your issue, but it does not solve question posted above since `receive` won't be triggered if you re-order the same list.